# JavaScript - Bing Maps - WellKnownText

Tags: javascript, maps, bing-maps, bing, wkt

I have the follow code:

```
var area = new Microsoft.Maps.WellKnownText.read(x, { strokeColor: stroke, strokeThickness: 10 });
$scope.map.setView({ center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lng), zoom: 17 });
$scope.map.entities.push(area);
```

Which should map a Well Known Text (wkt) string.  This works fine if I have a POINT() but for any other WKT String, it shows nothing.  I've looked at the MSDN example, but it only demonstrates POINT(), and no matter what I try, I can't get the other shapes to show up.

Has anyone been able to map shapes through the wkt handler?

Thanks
Docmur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the WKT module regularly with all sorts of shapes and haven't had any issues. Here is a larger sample that uses this module to load a large polygon: http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#North%20Carolina%20Map

Note that your code is incorrectly specifying styles. It should be using a StyleOptions object, also you shouldn't be using the "new" keyword as this is a static function:

```
var area = Microsoft.Maps.WellKnownText.read(x, { polygonOptions: { strokeColor: stroke, strokeThickness: 10 }});
```

Documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712880.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to be honest, I forgot about this post.  We solved this problem a while ago and I can't remember what the issue was.  We were having massive problems with CORS errors and 500 error codes from Bing Maps, which have disappeared.  Something was wrong with our key, at least that was the best guess they ever came up with.

We currently have the WKT mapping working like a treat.

Thanks
Docmur